# Issues getting Date Picker to show with MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Alright, so I'm trying to switch over from having to enter a manual date and time to using jquery to select the date and time.

I didnt think it would be too hard.

My View:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.DDate) %>       
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.DDate) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DDate)%> <br />
```

My Site.Master(I'm also using this: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
        $('.dp').datetimepicker({
            ampm: true
        }); 
</script>
```

DateTime.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>  
<%= Html.TextBox("",  String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp"})%>
```

Now I know somethings working right becuase when I load the page, there is a date preset with today's date.

However, when I click the textbox, NOTHING shows up.

Does anyone have an ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` is the right value for addon file name and `datetimepicker` is the right function name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try waiting for the document to be ready before manipulating it, otherwise at the time you execute your `$('.dp')` selector there is no corresponding elements loaded yet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.dp').datetimepicker({
            ampm: true
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Another possibility is to move this script at the end of your document (just before the closing `</body>`). This way you no longer need to wrap it in a `document.ready` handler.

Comment: @James, are you getting some javascript errors or something? Did you checkout the FireBug console? Are the paths to your javascript files correct? I see that you have hardcoded them instead of using url helpers which is the correct way to include static resources.

Comment: Checked firebug, found my issues, thanks! It turns out my files are in the Scripts folder, not Content, I never changed it from a previous thing I was using. I also changed my paths to use url helpers, thanks for the tip!